# Check address bar and redirect with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I would like to do the following:

Check address bar, if address is not something redirect to http://example.com else do nothing.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   if document.location != http://example.com
      window.location = 'http://example.com';
<script>
```

but it's not redirecting.

Please keep in min that the above code will be used in an `echo` tag in php.

**EDIT:**

I would also like be able to distinguish `http://example.com/app/1?someparameters` from `http://example.com/app/2?someparameters`

So if `http://example.com/app/2?someparameters` redirect to `http://example.com/app/1`

Already tried:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("http://example.com/app2/..") != -1) {
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/apps/1/";
        alert("Done");
    }
    else
       alert("OK"); 
    </script>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
if(window.top.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('http://example.com/app/2') != -1)
   window.top.location.href = 'http://example.com/app/1';
```

Comment: Please check my edited part. I think I need something like string.contain.

Comment: tried `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
  if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("http://example.com/app/1");
      alert("Done");
     }
     else
        alert("OK"); 
  </script>";` but its not working

Comment: Do you see any js error? Are you able to see the alert you have in the code?

Comment: No. I dont even see an alert. That's the problem

Comment: Your if condition is wrong. Look at my answer and do it that way.

Comment: Changed it. And now I can see the alert. I did `alert(window.location.href.toLowerCase())` but its displaying the location of the iframe instead of the original address bar location.

Comment: Its a Facebook Application mate. That's why. Is it possible to get the actual address bar address?

Comment: Ok, If you want to redirect the top window location, try my edited answer I have updated it.

Comment: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?ref=bookmarks from frame with URL http://mydomain.com/?ref=bookmarks. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: Yes you will face cross domain issues in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but with a number of changes:

1) `if` condition must be in parens

2) why do you check document.location, but assign to window.location? You should actually assign to `document.location.href`

3) the string in condition must be in quotes, of course:

```
if (document.location.href !== 'http://myhost.com')
    document.location.href = 'http://myhost.com'
```

Comment: Please check my edited part. I forgot to mentioned that. I think I need something like string.contain.